# media_handle_upload : undefined function?

Tags: uploads, media

I have been working with a front end upload and post creation script.  For some reason calling the media_handle_upload function from my project-save.php file is returning as an undefined function.  Is there something I a missing?  Permissions, additional files, coffee?

Here is my function in functions.php

```
function process_attachments() {
    //Process Uploads   
      if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
      }
       if ($_FILES) {
          foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
              if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                  return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
              }
              $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
          }   
      }

      //Attachment ID if set
      if ($attach_id > 0){
          //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
          return $attach_id;
      }
}
```

And I call this from my project-save.php file like so (this is slimmed down, I didnt feel the need to show the post creation form data)

```
$attach_id = process_attachments();
      if($attach_id > 0) {
          //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
          $whimkey->attach_id = $attach_id;
      }
```

Since `media_handle_upload` is a [Wordpress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) how could it be undefined?

Answer (score 5):

So I dont know if its the best way but my problem was the if statement surrounding the require_once on the necessary files that contain the function.  Commented out the IF statement and it did the trick.  I'll go have that coffee now ;)

```
//if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
      //}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you have put the wrong condition within if statement. You can check the first example here:
[Media handle upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload)